# How to check if Python Selenium Chrome headless is working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome-headless, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to implement Python Selenium Chrome headless, I have the code snippet below. When i try the same code without headless option, i can see the browser launch as well as the current url on the console. But when i use headless option, this goes into a stale state and i dont see the current url on the console.

```
chromedriver = "<chrome-driver-path>"
options = Options()
options.add_exprimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("window-size=1920x1080")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=options)
browser.get("<url>")
print(browser.current_url)
```

Note: all required libs imported

Versions:
python: 3.8.3,
selenium: 3.141.0,
chrome: 81.0.4044.129

Any guidance on how to successfully implement the headless option would really help

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your chrome with `Version 91.0.4472.77` and make following changes :

Instead of :

```
options.add_argument("headless")
```

use :

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

and Instead of :

```
print("browser.current_url")
```

use :

```
print(browser.current_url)
```

Comment: sorry on the  typo with print("browser.current_url"), tried using options.add_argument('--headless') that did not help much! was observing the same problem!

Comment: I have tried this `options.add_argument('--headless')` and `options.add_argument("headless")`, it does not matter actually. You need to remove double quotes

Comment: I tried options.add_argument('--headless') ,options.add_argument("headless") and options.headless=True.. but all three cases i was facing the same issue!

Comment: Your chrome is `chrome: 81.0.4044.129` , update this. I am using `Version 91.0.4472.77 ` and it works fine

Comment: got it, let me try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following which will check and install the latest version of Chrome every time:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```